# python/pandas pull specific column from multi-index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, indexing

Currently I have a multi-index as follows:

```
MultiIndex(levels=[[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
           names=['Date', 'Date'])
```

I was hoping to the get the second part of the labels, not the `[0,0,1,1]` but the `[10,11,0,1,2]` by itself. What would be the best possible way to do this?

As additional information my dataframe currently looks like this

```
df = 

                Date  Portfolio Value    SPY Values
Date Date                                          
2012 11   2012-11-30     1.002448e+06  1.003667e+06
     12   2012-12-28     9.817744e+05  9.887664e+05
2013 1    2013-01-25     1.042036e+06  1.061184e+06
     2    2013-02-22     1.050522e+06  1.072771e+06
     3    2013-03-29     1.094525e+06  1.106260e+06
     4    2013-04-26     1.130510e+06  1.117988e+06
     5    2013-05-31     1.145836e+06  1.154727e+06
     6    2013-06-28     1.146044e+06  1.131836e+06
     7    2013-07-26     1.190659e+06  1.194927e+06
     8    2013-08-30     1.138982e+06  1.155645e+06
     9    2013-09-27     1.182957e+06  1.193585e+06
     10   2013-10-25     1.248856e+06  1.242970e+06
     11   2013-11-29     1.292239e+06  1.278790e+06
     12   2013-12-27     1.320085e+06  1.298785e+06
2014 1    2014-01-31     1.266189e+06  1.258302e+06
     2    2014-02-28     1.304377e+06  1.316448e+06
     3    2014-03-28     1.297855e+06  1.310442e+06
     4    2014-04-25     1.298360e+06  1.316306e+06 etc...
```

and I was hoping to get the second `Date` index, starting from 11, 12, 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: `idx.labels[1]` ?

Comment: Why would you have duplicate names in your index?

Comment: @jpp I did not know the the implementation would be so easy, thank you! if you want to create this into an answer, I will accept it

Comment: @jpp I was trying to get the last date of the month from the previous dataframe and I did it like this 
`a = df.sort_values('Date').groupby([df.Date.dt.year, df.Date.dt.month]).last()`

and I ended with this result. If you have a way to make it more clearer I'd appreciate it!

Comment: In order to add more value and context to the community, could you give us some detail as to why you want access to the labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MultiIndex` labels are a `FrozenList` of `FrozenNDArray` objects.

You can simply access the second array via regular list indexing:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]],
                    labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6], [10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
                    names=['Date', 'Date'])

res = idx.labels[1]

print(res)

FrozenNDArray([10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], dtype='int8')
```

Comment: I was going to write an answer but thought it more appropriate to comment on your answer.  First off, this is imo the right answer.  However, Not sure if OP actually wants this.  Very rarely would you want to construct a MultiIndex by specifying the labels yourself.  When done correctly, the labels are simply a factorization of the values such that you can do `idx.levels[1][idx.labels[1]]` to get the same thing as `idx.get_level_values(1)`.  My point is, I'm questioning why OP would want to do this in the first place.

Comment: @piRSquared, That's a good point. Another point worth mentioning is `labels` won't always be consistent (if you concat dataframes with new values, I think they can change). I'll happily delete this if OP can confirm a new requirement.

Comment: I think you answered the question appropriately and it is useful.  I'd leave it.  It could be more useful if OP adds some color (which I asked).  Also, you are right about the concat.  It can do some wonky things.